# Prolog list of sum of elements with this same indexes from two lists

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and I am looking for an example on how to think about resolving things such a:
We have two lists and we need a new list that is combined from sum of elements with this same indexes from two lists.

```
?-sm([1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6],X).
 X=[4,6,8,10].
```

How we should resolve this?

Comment: `?- sm(A,B,C) :- maplist(plus, A,B,C).`

Comment: one way is, by recursion. just following the list datatype definition as being a pair of an element and a list, or an empty list.

Comment: It is a hard piece of bread.

Comment: Some basic tutorials and examples should give you ideas for at least getting started. Have a look through [99 Prolog Problems](https://sites.google.com/site/prologsite/prolog-problems), particularly the ones dealing with lists. You should find it helpful. The bread isn't as had as you think if you just study it a bit. :)

Comment: Okey, I will try to learn some more, but Prolog seems to be very different that typical imperative programming language.

Comment: still don't know how to start. what could be a base for a recursive definition?

Comment: and, `sm([A|B], [C|D], .......) :- E is A+C, ......, sm(B, D, .....).`.

Comment: This is helpfull, but in case to make this independent of number of elements of `sm` I need to sleep and try next day. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The only suitable way to work with simply-linked lists (in any language) is to first process the head, and then to process the rest.

So we just take the head of each list, process them, and continue on (the result of operation makes the head of the rest of the result list).

In prolog this gets expressed as:

```
sm([],[],[]). % we reached the end
sm([Head1|Rest1],[Head2|Rest2],[ResultHead|RestResult]) :-
    ResultHead is Head1 + Head2, % '=' unifies, 'is' computes !!!
    sm(Rest1,Rest2,RestResult).
```

I'm keeping it simple for now - I see at least two concerns with this solution, let's discover them interactively and extend the answer ;-)

EDITED: sm([],[]). was of course wrong (different arity => different predicate).

corrected to sm([],[],[]).

Comment: We need to append result of each iteration to some list and after all return it. How can I provide here (and where) another variable?

Comment: why does this does not work?
`sm([], []).
sm([Head1|Rest1], [Head2|Rest2], R) :- ResultElem is Head1 + Head2, append([ResultElem], R, R), sm(Rest1, Rest2, R).`

Comment: @krzyhub `append([ResultElem], R, R)` can't ever succeed, because `append(A,B,C)` means that `length(C) == length(A) + length(B)`.

Comment: I got it by another question, but without your help there will be nothing. Thank you.

Comment: small bug, sm([],[]) was missing one argument - [].   In prolog, dm/2 and dm/3 are entirely different predicates.